# Does g++ still generate an output file even if the program fails to compile/load?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++

I am compiling some C++ programs through a perl script using:

```
g++ -o out `find ./ -iname "*.h" -or -iname "*.cpp"`
```

This seems to generate an an `out` file every time, regardless of whether the program compiled successfully or not.
Whenever the script tries to run programs like this, it gets permission errors (weird since I'm running as `root`).
Is this accurate and if so, how can I prevent it?

Thanks.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but: There is no reason to include *.h files on the compiler command line. It does nothing with them.

Comment: Because the script that is running this is written in perl and that might be relevant information.

Comment: How are you running this in your Perl program? The code given isn't Perl, so if it's a Perl problem we need to see your Perl code.

Comment: I am not actually running as root, I am running the script using sudo. Also, I run this in the perl program using system(). Sorry for any mixup.

Comment: Is it possible that a file named `out` existed previously?

Comment: Wait, I must have missed that. Why in the world are you _compiling as root_? Oh man, this is so messed up!

Comment: Why not use a proper build tool?

Comment: I am building a one-off solution to compile and run some code and check their output. There isn't enough going on to go through the trouble of a build tool.  
I was running as root to check some error, its not actually the way the tool is supposed to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to your title's question ("Does g++ still generate an output file even if the program fails to compile/load?") is no:

```
% echo blah > test.cpp
% g++ -o out test.cpp
test.cpp:1: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion at end of input
% ls *out*
/bin/ls: *out*: No such file or directory
%
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it as follows:
For some reason, trying to put the output executable using `-o out` seemed to force creating the file even after the compile failed (it seems to me).

Answer (score 0):

```
g++ -o out.tmp `find ./ -iname "*.h" -or -iname "*.cpp"` && mv out.tmp out
```